# How to match the versions of jupyterlab-nvdashboard and JupyterLab

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I am trying to [clara-train-example](https://github.com/NVIDIA/clara-train-examples/tree/master/PyTorch/NoteBooks) with gpu monitoring tools. I get the error when I run
`startClaraTrainNoteBooks.sh`

```
ValueError: The extension "jupyterlab-nvdashboard" does not yet support the current version of JupyterLab.


Conflicting Dependencies:
JupyterLab              Extension        Package
>=3.0.6 <3.1.0          >=2.0.0 <3.0.0   @jupyterlab/application
>=3.0.5 <3.1.0          >=2.0.0 <3.0.0   @jupyterlab/apputils
>=5.0.3 <5.1.0          >=4.0.0 <5.0.0   @jupyterlab/coreutils
>=17.0.1 <18.0.0        >=16.4.2 <17.0.0 react
>=17.0.1 <18.0.0        >=16.9.0 <17.0.0 react-dom
See the log file for details:  /tmp/jupyterlab-debug-53dt6_x5.log
```

I don’t understand the content of log.
Many thank your help.

Comment: In your case this would be [`pip install jupyterlab-nvdashboard`](https://pypi.org/project/jupyterlab-nvdashboard/) as explained in the [README of jupyterlab-nvdashboard](https://github.com/rapidsai/jupyterlab-nvdashboard).

Comment: @krassowski It is meaning that I just need to run `pip install jupyterlab-nvdashboard` and don't need to run `jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-nvdashboard`?

Comment: Yes, exactly just pip.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @krassowski, commenting out `RUN jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-nvdashboard` in the appropriate DockerFile at clara-train-examples/PyTorch/NoteBooks/scripts/dockerWGPUDashboardPlugin/Dockerfile fixed the issue once the GPUDashboard is enabled in the `docker-compose.yml` file, i.e.:

```
##### to build image with GPU dashboard inside jupyter lab
build:
  context: ./dockerWGPUDashboardPlugin/    # Project root
  dockerfile: ./Dockerfile                 # Relative to context
image: clara-train-nvdashboard:v4.0
```